# Script não autenticado

Tags: script, autenticação, navegador-de-internet

Vez ou outra me deparo com um ícone na barra do navegador, afirmando que a página está tentando carregar `scripts` de uma fonte não autenticada.

Por que isso ocorre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problema

Isso acontece quando a pagina é https e é usado um link apenas com http no src do script.

**Exemplo**

Url da pagina:

```
https:\\wwww.minhapagina.com.br
```

Script utilizado:

```
<script src="http:\\wwww.minhapagina.com.br\meuscript.js"></script>
```

## Solução

**Para carregar o script** (Exemplo do google chrome)

Para ver a página inteira:

1. À direita da barra de endereço, clique em Conteúdo bloqueado Conteúdo bloqueado.
2. No alerta, clique em Carregar todo o site.
3. A página será carregada.

Se o erro mencionar scripts, você poderá ver a página inteira clicando em Carregar script não seguro.

Fonte: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=pt-BR

Comment: O script é carregado sim.

Comment: Minto, eu que já deixei carregado aqui no meu navegador.

Comment: tem este link que você consegue ativar o script: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=pt-BR

Comment: Editei a pergunta mostrando como ativar no google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Wictor Chaves está correta em partes.

Também tem a seguinte questão: você carregou o javascript como HTTPS mas ele faz uma chamada ajax sem usar HTTPS (para uma página php por exemplo), também dará o alerta de que o script está tentando carregar um script de fonte não autenticada.

Resumindo, use HTTPS em tudo.